# Dismiss UISwipeActionsConfiguration by swiping back

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

I implemented trailing swipe actions using new iOS 11 `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` API, and I can reveal them by swiping from the edge, can swipe all the way to the left side etc.

But I can't hide those actions by swiping back to original position. If I drag a little bit to the left and then back to the right it does dismiss (see gif). It also gets dismissed by tapping on a cell.

The official Mail app does support dragging to hide swipe actions, so there may be a way in the API too.

See sample project here: https://github.com/nezhyborets/ios-case-study-playgrounds/tree/master/UISwipeActionsConfiguration

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Great question!

This is not a direct configuration, but if you also implement an action for `leading` in addition to your existing `trailing`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "bla") { (action, view, success) in
        success(true)
    }
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
}
```

This will give you the desired effect.

Unfortunately, this requires an action for swiping right. I tried making the `actions` array `[]`, but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 6):

```
// Create a destructive context action
let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (myContext, myView, complete) in

    // Did what you wanted to do
    complete(true)

    // Cancelled the action
    complete(false)
}
```